# why my @types/react will it affect my upper level files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js

[image]

[image]

My directory structure looks like this

```
vue
  node_modules
  src
    react_app
      node_modules
        @types/react
      package.json
  ...other file
  package.json
```

Why does the @ types of a subdirectory affect the top-level directory?

I tried using GPT to help me solve, but it didn't work,I hope @types/react does not affect the upper level directory

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional, TypeScript applies type declarations to the whole project scope. This allows TypeScript to have seperate module type declarations for Javascript only modules, while still having some type-safety. In this case: `@types/react` helps catch an error here.

In this case, we actually need to pass an object to style. This is because what you have written is a [jsx element](https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx), not an html element.

> JSX is a syntax extension for JavaScript that lets you write HTML-like markup inside a JavaScript file.

While it looks similar, and this sort of abstraction does map almost one-to-one some attributes are different, while in JSX they are referred to as properties. Notably from HTML to JSX are some examples of attributes being renamed `class` -> `className` and `for` -> `htmlFor` (these two are notable because `class` and `for` are reserved keywords in javascript).

This is also true of the `style` attribute, but rather than renaming we choose to accept an object instead (the specific typing can be found in `@types/react`, but limits key/value pairs to valid css values). This will ensure our styling is correct and will have real css properties and valid values on it. The proper way to inline style this is as follows:

```
<span style={isButtonClick ? {opacity: 0} : undefined}>
  {/** ... */}
</span>
```

Comment: thanks you answer，But it is a vue file that uses template syntax instead of using jsx. in  vue template syntax， style prop supports objects and strings, but when I install @type/react in react_app, it became only supportive of objects